# Visual Studio Generated .dll files from .resx files allways contain changes

Tags: visual-studio-2019, resx

I'm facing a strange issue that I can't wrap my head around..

I'm using Resx Manager extension to create strings for different languages (de/it..)

I have a Resources.resx file where I only have strings with text that is displayed on GUI. Text here is in english, which is default language.
Then I use Resx Manager to type in translations for other languages.
This creates Resources.de.resx, Resources.it.resx... files.
When I build the solution, this generates .dll files in the output directory. (Each language gets its own folder - ex: /de, /it)

All of this works as expected, however these .dll files ALLWAYS contain changes, even if I don't change anything. Just simply running second build after initial build will cause the output .dll file to have changes. The output directory is under subversion control, meaning that any actual change in some other file is overshadowed by the 60+ changes in these language .dll files.

I can't figure out what is causing the issue here.. Comparing the file from first and second build, I can confirm that there is indeed some change in the file, but it is just some binary data, for which I have no clue where its coming from..

I want VS to only change .dll files if the strings in .resx files actualy have changes.

Any help or any information on how to debug this would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: The *.dll contains a timestamp that will change every time you build. You should not have your output directory under source control, or at least exclude binary files from being tracked.

Comment: This is by design.  If any of the source code files of a project changed then you always get a fresh .dll when you build, including the satellite assemblies.  MSBuild isn't smart enough to suppress that, nor is it practical to add those smarts yourself.  Keep your eye on the real problem, checking these .dlls into source control is very unusual and something you really want to avoid.  Something like a build server, capable of instantly providing those .dlls when you need them is a standard strategy.

Comment: But other .cs projects within solution are also rebuilt as .dll, and they are not detected as having changes due to timestamp? Is this something .resx specific then?
They have to be in source control, because the resulting .exe uses them to display text in german, italian, etc.. (The SVN is checked out on the target machine)
Without these files, the text on GUI will allways be in english..

So I Guess I have no choice but to somehow rework this Localization feature.. 
Probably switching to json/xml so that it will be human readable too.

Thanks for your replies!